# Custom HorizontalScrollView for android

Tags: java, android, animation, horizontalscrollview

I'm developing a very simple app that requires me to create a 3 image slideshow sort of deal. I'm new at android java development and i've got no clue how to go around this, i've been searching for answers around and didn't find any suitable one (and to be more precise - i don't even know what to search for).

So here's how it should look:

[image]

So it only has 3 pictures, and you can swipe left and right and the images swap with the frontal one. Should be very simple, was able to get it in swift under 45 minutes but i can't get it working properly in java. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look up ViewPager in android. You get the desired result through that with ease.

Comment: Post the code you tried.

Comment: You can refer this link: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/

Comment: Ì've tried plenty of things, didn't try with ViewPagers and i'm about to now. I can get it to work in a slide show manner but not animated to slide like on the picture i posted above.

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/crosswall/Android-Coverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's called ***CoverFlow***. You can find many library. search at [GitHub](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=android+coverflow&type=)

Here is some library with good demo

1. [Android-Coverflow](https://github.com/crosswall/Android-Coverflow)
2. [CoverFlow](https://github.com/moondroid/CoverFlow)
3. [FeatureCoverFlow](https://github.com/SemonCat/FeatureCoverFlow)

Comment: This is exactly what i need! Thanks.

Comment: @Kishore Link only answers are bad. you need to provide code also for other user who came here in future in-case link will changed

Comment: @AbhishekSingh He need guide not a code and GitHub link(see first line) will never expire :)

Comment: I've tried everything and i still can't get the results i need. I probably didn't explain well in the question itself. I need the center image to always stay centered, and rotate the others around. So if you swipe left, it pushes right to the center, left to the right and right to the left.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the library that i have found for your requirement
https://code.google.com/archive/p/carousel-layout-android/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the library which match your requirement.
You can try [this](https://github.com/crosswall/Android-Coverflow), [this](https://github.com/moondroid/CoverFlow) and [this](https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow) library. This will help you out.